# Calculation Resolvent/$\alpha$-Potential of Brownian Motion/Wiener Process

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, brownian-motion, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

I'm interested in a laplace transform of the heat/gaussian kernel, precisely for $x,y\in \Bbb R ^p$ and $\mu > 0$:
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\mu t} \frac 1 {(2\pi t)^{\frac p 2}} e^{-\frac{||x-y||^2}{2t}} \text{d} t = ?$$

My approaches were several substitutions right up to solution operators for the $\mu$-eigenvalue problem of the scaled laplacian.
I know there is a explicit representation for $p=3$ and I remember finding an expression for it a while ago, but with aid of a bessel funtion.

I would appreciate any help or useful reference to this problem.

Comment: You can take a look at the book on Brownian motion by Schilling & Partzsch. It contains some computations in this direction

Comment: Thank you for this reference. Indeed they compute p=1, but give no calculation for the other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from the book "Brownian Motion: An Introduction to Stochastic Processes" by Schilling/Partzsch:

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-\mu t} \frac 1 {(2\pi t)^{\frac p 2}} e^{-\frac{||x-y||^2}{2t}} \text{d} t = 
\begin{cases} \frac 1 { \sqrt{2\mu}}  e^{-\sqrt{2\mu}|y-x|} &: p=1 \\
\frac 1 {\pi^{\frac  p 2}} \left(\frac \mu {2(y-x)^2}\right)^{\frac p 4 - \frac 1 2} K_{\frac p 2 -1}(\sqrt{2\mu}(y-x)) &: p \geq 2 \end{cases},$$
where $K_\nu(z)$ is a Bessel function of the third kind.
In the book "Essentials of Brownian Motion and Diffusions" by Frank B. Knight he gives expressions for this in form of green functions for the PDE $\mu u - \frac 1 2 \Delta u = 0$, then for p=3:
$$\frac 1 {2\pi |x-y|} e^{- \sqrt{2\mu}|x-y|}$$

Comment: Why is $\int_0^\infty e^{-\mu t} \frac 1 {(2\pi t)^{\frac p 2}} e^{-\frac{||x-y||^2}{2t}} \text{d} t$ the resolvent, you also have to integrate over $y$? Or am i wrong?

Comment: It is nowhere said that this was the resolvent. The quantity of interest in this post is in fact the integral kernel of the resolvent operator of the gaussian Markov semigroup interpreted as integral operator on functions.